# Simulating keyboard input in Delphi using WinAPI

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-2009

I need to programmatically enter one character into a cell of a Delphi grid (in other application).

In order to do this manually, following steps are required:

1. Press the F3 button.
2. Press the right-arrow key 3 times.
3. Press the space button.
4. Type letter 'E' on the keyboard.
5. Press the right-arrow key.

   ```
    // Press F3 button         
    keybd_event(VK_F3, 0, 0, 0);         
    // Press right arrow key 3 times
    keybd_event(VK_RIGHT, 0, 0, 0);
    keybd_event(VK_RIGHT, 0, 0, 0);
    keybd_event(VK_RIGHT, 0, 0, 0);

    // Press the space button
    keybd_event(VK_SPACE, 0, 0, 0);

    // Type letter E
    keybd_event(Ord('E'), 0, 0, 0);

    // Move to the right
    keybd_event(VK_RIGHT, 0, 0, 0);
   ```

But it doesn't work. When I run this code, nothing seems to happen.

How should I modify this code so that it actually simulates user input?

Comment: I've made something about [`virtual keyboard`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12565963/960757) some time ago (and there will be many others). But to your problem, if you are targeting `TStringGrid`, I think you can't do anything else than focus it and simulate your keystrokes (if I remember that right, `TStringGrid` doesn't respond to any kind of message that would be able to set the text of a cell).

Comment: In this particular application it is possible to enter values into that grid only via keyboard. I've done this already with AutoHotKey and MS UI Automation, but now need to rewrite this code in Delphi.

Comment: I can't rely on the grid being focused because there is a program on the target system, which activates itself every 200 milliseconds.

Comment: You can try to use the `WM_KEYDOWN`, `WM_KEYUP` messages, but I'm not sure it will always work between two processes...

Comment: Here is un example (with source code) of autoclic that simulates keystrokes and mouse clicks and then play them in a sequence.
http://delphimagic.blogspot.com.es/2010/03/autoclic-con-delphi.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Each key press is a key down and then a key up. So you need two calls to `keybd_event` per key press. For example, to press F3:

```
keybd_event(VK_F3, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN, 0);
keybd_event(VK_F3, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

Note that `KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN` isn't actually defined by the Windows header files, or the Delphi translation. Define it to be `0`. It makes the code clearer written out explicitly though.

Naturally you would not litter your code with paired calls to `keybd_event`. But instead you would wrap up the paired calls into a helper function.

It's possible that in some situations you would need to specify the second parameter, the scan code. But it's often not necessary.

Comment: Thanks. Does `keybd_event` work, when the control in question is NOT focused?

Comment: @DmitriPisarenko Not it does not. Input messages go to the control with the input focus.

Comment: Is it possible to replace `keybd_event` calls with sending windows messages to the grid?

Comment: @DmitriPisarenko Probably. Use `PostMessage` with `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_KEYUP`.

Comment: Regarding `lParam` of `WM_KEYUP` message. According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646281(v=vs.85).aspx there are 3 1-bits in `lParam`, which gives me a value of `0x8000C`. Reason: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/11776689/2012_10_18_delphi_winapi_bits.png Is this correct?

Comment: That's a different question altogether. I think I answered the question that you asked.

Comment: Ad `lParam` for `WM_KEYUP`: It seems to be `0xC0000001`.

Comment: It is, but I wanted to make sure that everything works as it should. In the meantime, I encountered and fixed another problem ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954545/strange-wm-char-behaviour-wrong-chcharcode ). Now the code seems to do what it should and I marked the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://github.com/WladiD/SendInputHelper  by Mr. Waldemar Derr.

Example:

```
uses
  ..., SendInputHelper;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  SIH: TSendInputHelper;
begin
  SIH := TSendInputHelper.Create;
  try
    // Start command shell
    SIH.AddShortCut([ssWin], 'r'); // Win+R
    SIH.AddDelay(100);
    SIH.AddText('cmd', True); // Second parameter True means AppendReturn
    SIH.AddDelay(500);

    SIH.AddText('ping google.de', True); // Perform a ping.

    SIH.Flush; // Isn't it easy?
  finally
    SIH.Free;
  end;
end;
```