# Strange WM_CHAR behaviour (wrong chCharCode)

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-2009

I need to automate entering a certain character (Russian letter `Э`). In Spy++ the corresponding message looks like this:

`WM_CHAR chCharCode: '221' (221) cRepeat:1 ScanCode:28 fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0`

[image]

In order to send this message programmatically, I use this Delphi code:

`SendMessage(Self.PassengerGrid, WM_CHAR, WPARAM(221), LPARAM($280001));`

When I examine the results of running my code in Spy++, I see following message:

`WM_CHAR chCharCode: '89' (89) cRepeat:1 ScanCode:28 fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0`

Something must be wrong with `wParam` of my `SendMessage` call.

How can I fix it (so that the `chCharcode` is equal to `221`)` ?

**Update 1:**

- The machine, where this error occurs, has two keyboard languages - English and Russian.
- I noticed that when the following code

  SendMessage(MyGridHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_OEM_7, LPARAM($390000));
  SendMessage(MyGridHandle, WM_CHAR, WPARAM(221), LPARAM($280001));
  SendMessage(MyGridHandle, WM_KEYUP, VK_OEM_7, LPARAM($c0390001));

is executed, the selected language (according to tray icon) changes from Russian to English.

- Whatever character I transmit in WM_CHAR, `WPARAM` of the message is always `0x59` (`89`).

**Update 2:** Using `WM_UNICHAR` instead of `WM_CHAR` doesn't help.

Comment: check the Wparam parameter in Spy++, It won't be 221. Please consult the manual : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646268%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Please look at the screenshot. It shows keyboard messages, when I type the letter `Э` manually.

Comment: @DmitriPisarenko You might also look at [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310%28VS.85%29.aspx). It is specifically for sending keystrokes (and other input) to external applications.

Comment: @whosrdaddy WPARAM is equal to `0xDD` (221).

Comment: @satuon Does `SendInput` work when the target application is *not* focused?

Comment: I have no idea. You'll need to test that.

Comment: If you need Russian 'Э' you should send 1069 instead of 221

Comment: @Serg Thanks. And what is the corresponding scan code?

Comment: I guess scan code does not matter, I tried with LPARAM = 0 and it worked

Comment: @Serg Yes, it works! Please paste your suggestion as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should send UTF-16 code of a character as WPARAM (that is 1069 for Russian 'Э'), ex:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PostMessage(Edit1.Handle, WM_CHAR, WPARAM(1069), LPARAM(0));//$280001));
end;
```

Comment: In recent Delphi versions, you could also just type  PostMessage(Edit1.Handle, WM_CHAR, WPARAM('Э'), LPARAM(0));

Comment: @DanBartlett - your code does not work on Delphi XE for me (WPARAM('Э') = 221).