# Paste text from clipboard to a text area input box on a webpage

Tags: html, delphi, textarea

I have worked with the clipboard in Delphi so no help there. I have a website that has 10 text area boxes, and I need to paste some text from my Delphi VCL app into these textareas on the webpage.

Here is one of the text area on the page:

```
<textarea name="txtGoalTransaction275746_0" rows="3" cols="20" 
          id="txtGoalTransaction275746_0" 
          onkeyup="Count(this, 5000)" onchange="Count(this, 5000)" 
          style="width:400px;"></textarea>
```

I can not use `TWebbrowser` as the website does not work correctly in `TWebbrowser`.

I am looking for a method to paste from clipboard into the textarea from my Delphi VCL app.

Any help is appreciated.

I can log into the site fine with

```
JSCode := 'document.getElementById("username").value = "myusername";' +
'document.getElementById("pwd").value = "myPaseword";' +
'document.forms[0].submit();';
```

So I know I am working with edgebrowser ok.

I am trying

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   EdgeBrowser1.ExecuteScript(
    'document.getElementById("txtGoalTransaction271900_0").value ="Test String"');
end;
```

But nothing gets put in the textarea.

I wonder if there is a way to enumerate all the elements that are on the webpage that is displayed in tedgebrowser.

Comment: Which version of Delphi are you using? The typical way to handle this is to use the browser's DOM, but that doesn't work if you are not embedding the browser in your app. Recent versions of Delphi have a new TEdgeBrowser that replaces TWebBrowser. There are also 3rd party embedded browsers, like CEF4DELPHI

Comment: Do you even need to occupy the clipboard (overwriting existing content)? Or do you just want to set the content of any `textarea` and overly concluded this can only be done via clipboard? [Sending a simulating `Ctrl+V`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12951053/4299358) to "_the webpage_" should also be possible.

Comment: Do you control how the we page is displayed? Like, is it in a specific browser? Doesn't seem like any of your tags are relevant and the question is really about automating a browser.

Comment: The Javascript (from my answer) to update the textarea does work. If it doesn't on your webpage, then maybe the page hasn't loaded yet, or maybe the element ID is wrong? Or maybe something else specific with that web page. Your new question has plenty of answers if you google "enumerate all the elements on a webpage by elementid with javascript".

Answer (score 2):

If you have Delphi 10.4.2 or higher, you can use the `TEdgeBrowser` component.

Once the web page is loaded into the browser, you can use the TEdgeBrowser's `ExecuteScript` method. It runs arbitrary Javascript. You can thus use JavaScript from Delphi to set the value of the textarea, like this:

```
EdgeBrowser1.ExecuteScript(
  'document.getElementById(''txtGoalTransaction275746_0'').value = ''Some text to your liking!'';');
```

To answer your specific question, the contents of the clipboard would be used like this:

```
uses 
  Vcl.Clipbrd;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  EdgeBrowser1.ExecuteScript(
    'document.getElementById(''txtGoalTransaction275746_0'').value = ''' +
    Clipboard.AsText + ''';');
end;
```

For TEdgeBrowser to work, you need to have Microsoft's WebView2 Run-Time installed, and WebView2Loader.dll must be present in your EXE file's directory.